# Limiting concurrent access to a field

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, atomicreference

So in a program I'm writing I use a bi-directional breadth first search to search a graph. I do this by running 1 breadth first search in 1 thread, and one in another. Now the search is said to have found the optimal solution when it either an element from the other search is hit, or when the goal is found (which never really happens, but just in case it does for some reason..).

The problem I am running into, is that I need to save this optimal solution to a field, because I need to continue to find all of the solutions, but the field value is getting messed up because both threads hit it at the same time (I think).

Is there a way to block access to the thread who gets there last? I've tried using an AtomicReference and its compareAndSet method but that didn't do the trick. The value still gets messed up....

Btw I'm using java, and for the threads I'm using Callable objects.

Comment: Isn't there an inherent flaw in your design? Say both searches are on the first element of level 5, and they find each other.  You would consider the shortest path to be 10.  But if the second element of level 5 in the first search WAS in the second graph's visited nodes, there could possibly be a 9-length solution.

Comment: @Mark I keep track of which nodes have been visited by each search and check for the opposite set membership before adding it. Basically when an intersection occurs in the set, the solution is said to be found. I should have made my implementation clearer

Comment: Ok I think I fixed the example in my "answer".  I'm really interested how you get the correct answer in that scenario.  Maybe I'm misinterpreting your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a possible `Livelock` or [`Race condition`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) that is occuring because of the random order of threads. I'd recommending taking a different approach. (otherwise at some point you will run into [`NP-Complete`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete)).

> The problem I am running into, is that I need to save this **optimal solution** to a field. **because I need to continue to find all of the solutions**, but the field value is getting messed up because both threads hit it at the same time (I think).

There is a way to greatly increase your current technique. You shouldn't need to look at every solution, take a [`Greedy Approach`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) and use a [`Paralleled version`](http://www.cslab.ece.ntua.gr/~anastop/files/papers/mtaap09dijkstra.pdf) of [`Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm).

**Shortest Path (or in your case *Optimal Solution*)**

> Dijkstra's Algorithm is a graph search algorithm that solves the single-source shortest path problem for a graph with nonnegative edge path costs, producing a shortest path tree. This algorithm is often used in routing and as a subroutine in other graph algorithms.

**Linear Implementation**

The original algorithm Figure 1. ([Source](http://www.cslab.ece.ntua.gr/~anastop/files/papers/mtaap09dijkstra.pdf))

[image: Parallel PDF Algorithm Linear]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/w4b43s1r.34o.png))</sub>

Java Implementations can be found [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130905005651/http://renaud.waldura.com:80/doc/java/dijkstra/), and [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.htm)

- *I think these implementations are based on BSP Trees (but you should get the idea)*

**Parallel Implementation**

The parallel algorithm Figure 2. ([Source](http://www.cslab.ece.ntua.gr/~anastop/files/papers/mtaap09dijkstra.pdf))

- There are additional ways to speed up the algorithm with `recursion`, if you want to get classy.

[image: Parallel PDF Algorithm Atomic]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/15ndcts5.p3a.png))</sub>

Another idea if you are still having problems, might be to use a different concurrent data structure like `Map Reduce` or `Hadoop` instead of using `Threads` to search through a `Binary Tree`, to fix your search.

Comment: well the thing is...I do need to find every solution. It's part of the project specification....I suppose I can find all solutions (which doesn't take much longer) and then sort by length to get the shortest solution, but seeing as how there is some extra credit that is going to be assigned arbitrarily, I want to have the optimal solution pop up in under a second (which is achievable using my current method, if I merely return immediately upon finding a solution).

However that looks like great food for thought! Thank you for the input I will definitely read over it!!

Comment: Read into [Travelling Sales Man Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) is a problem in Computer Science that is `NP-Hard` (which means people are yet to solve it in polynomial time), The problem with looking at every solution, is what happens when you have the `vertex` range of say `google maps` 2 million possible solutions on each search. In theory your application should scale. Kindest Regards

Comment: My data set is much smaller and I know for a fact that it won't grow to sizes which make it effectively impossible.

Comment: Oh okay, thats understandable either way this solution should be able to find you the shortest path in under a second (its designed for large data sets, its the algorithm google uses in its map results). From my understanding of your current approach is going to take you [`O(x o(1+r)^t)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth) (with a large possibility of `race conditions`, even with [`speed up`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup) being taken into consideration) where `Dijkstra's` can do it in [`O(n log(n))`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Kindest Regards

Comment: [Computiational Complexity of Dijkstras Algorithm](http://computersciencesource.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/shortest-path-dijkstras-algorithm/) (Article doesn't take `speed up` into consideration, its about the linear speed).

Comment: after doing some more reading, I think that a variation of the parallel dijkstras is what I'm after....

Comment: In the algorithm description where it says barrier, I assume in java that would be a synchronized block, does that create a barrier to the graph itself?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16519/discussion-between-killrawr-and-ethan)

Comment: @Ethan yeah the barrier would be the `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: not an answer, just checking the validity of the algorithm**

Does your algorithm actually yield the shortest path?  Consider this graph:

```
 1A - 2A - 3A - 4A - 5A
  \             /     
   -- 2B -------
```

And assume perfect interweaving (the threads each visit nodes at the exact same rate).  Thread `X` starts at `1A` and thread `Y` starts at `5A`.  The order would look like this:

```
X visits 1A +{2A, 2B}
Y visits 5A +{4A}
X visits 2A +{3A}
Y visits 4A +{3A, 2B}
X visits 2B +{4A}
Y visits 3A +{2A}
X visits 3A (overlap; shortest path is computed to be 4)
```

But we know from inspection that the shortest path is 3: `1A - 2B - 4A - 5A`.

How does your approach prevent this case?  No matter which approach you take for checking for duplicates, I always see `3A` overlapping before `2B`.  Do you always finish out the "level" before making a decision on what the optimal path length is?